# Return 0 count on jonined query in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following db schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA products;

CREATE TABLE products.product_group (
  id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE products.product (
  id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  product_group_id bigint REFERENCES products.product_group(id),
  color varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO products.product_group(name) values ('product group 1');

INSERT INTO products.product(name,product_group_id,color) VALUES ('product 1',1,'RED'); 
INSERT INTO products.product(name,product_group_id,color) VALUES ('product 1',1,'BLUE'); 
INSERT INTO products.product(name,product_group_id,color) VALUES ('product 1',1,'GREEN');
```

If I execute the following query:

```
SELECT count(*), pg.name  FROM products.product p
LEFT JOIN products.product_group pg ON (p.product_group_id=pg.id)
WHERE pg.id = 1
AND  p.color = 'RED'
GROUP BY pg.name
```

I get the result:

```
1;"product group 1"
```

If I execute the following query:

```
SELECT count(*), pg.name  FROM products.product p
LEFT JOIN products.product_group pg ON (p.product_group_id=pg.id)
WHERE pg.id = 1
AND  p.color = 'YELLOW'
GROUP BY pg.name
```

I get *no results*, bu I want to have:

```
0;"product group 1"
```

How do I need to change the query to get the result I want to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count(p.name), pg.name
FROM
    products.product p
    right JOIN
    products.product_group pg ON
        p.product_group_id=pg.id
        and pg.id = 1
        and p.color = 'YELLOW'
GROUP BY pg.name;
 count |      name       
-------+-----------------
     0 | product group 1
```

Your original query has two problems. First the outer join is backwards. Second the where conditions turns the outer join into an inner join so the `where` conditions must be moved to the `join` conditions.

There is another issue with the counting. You must declare a column in the `count` so it only counts where that column is not null.